# How to add external tools menu on different version of Visual Studio programmatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio, registry

I need to write a small code, which need to add some items in external tools menu, but in programmatical way.

and it need to work on all different visual studios, 2008, 2010, 2012, 2013, and all express versions of these versions.

I know it's about add registry keys, but I heard several different locations of registry:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\External Tools

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\WDExpress\12.0\External Tools

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VCExpress\9.0\External Tools

and so on.

how to get the correct location from the user? because the names after the Microsoft are different.

or is there any other ways to add those tools programmatically?